# T sql group by only column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have **columns** as below in **Products** Table

```
name varchar(100)

xdate datetime
```

If i select below query from **Products** Table

```
select name
     , DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) as xdate  
from Products
```

**select query result** as below

**name (column)  - xdate (column)**

```
Computer    May

Phone   May

Mouse  May

Grass  April

Usb  April

Glass  February
```

**Question:**

How can i display result as below

**name (column)  - xdate (column)**

```
    Computer    May

    Phone   

    Mouse  

    Grass  April

    Usb  

    Glass  February
```

I only want to display **xdate** once what to chage in my select query in order to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is almost always far better dealt with in whatever program/report formatter/other consumer is taking this result set rather than trying to do it in TSQL. Also, if you want it done only on changes, you probably need to add an `ORDER BY` so that results from the same month occur "together".

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
select 
    name, 
    case when num = 1 then xdate else '' end as xdate
from
(
    select 
        name, 
        DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(xdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) as xdate  ,
        row_number() over (partition by YEAR(XDATE), MONTH(XDATE) order by xdate) as num,
        xdate as real_date
    from Products
) T
order by real_date
```

Comment: edited answer: row_number() should be ordered by xdate

Answer (score 2):

How is your data ordered? Assuming you have an ordering column (id in the example below), you can use the LAG function on SQL Server 2012 and higher:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE
(id int, name varchar(100), xdate varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @Products (id, name, xdate)
VALUES
(1, 'Computer', 'May'),
(2, 'Phone', 'May'),
(3, 'Mouse', 'May'),
(4, 'Grass', 'April'),
(5, 'Usb', 'April'),
(6, 'Glass', 'February')

SELECT p.name,
    CASE LAG(p.xdate, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY p.id)
        WHEN p.xdate THEN ''
        ELSE p.xdate
    END AS xdate
FROM @Products p
```

Results:

```
name        xdate
Computer    May
Phone   
Mouse   
Grass       April
Usb 
Glass       February
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL 2012+, I think George has the best solution.

### SQL 2005 Solution

```
SELECT  P.id,
        name,
        ISNULL(CA.xdate,'') AS xDate
FROM Products p
OUTER APPLY(
                SELECT DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(xdate) , 0 ) - 1 )
                FROM Products
                GROUP BY xdate
                HAVING MIN(ID) = p.id
           ) CA(xdate)
ORDER BY ID
```

### SQL 2008 Solution

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CA.xDate ORDER BY ID) = 1
                THEN CA.xdate
            ELSE ''
        END AS xdate
FROM Products
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(xdate) , 0 ) - 1 )) CA(xdate)
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

And a lower tech (less elegant) solution (that would work on SQL Server 2000):

```
select t.name, case when t.name = minSQ.minName then minSQ.mnth else '' end 
from Products t 
    join (select MIN(name) minName, DATENAME(month,xdate) mnth from Products group by DATENAME(month,xdate)) minSQ on DateName(month, t.xdate) = minSQ.mnth
order by t.xdate
```